# Three File Comparision in PowerShell with current date

Tags: powershell, scripting, compare

I am writing a script to compare these three particular files in a folder with current date. 
I want to compare the first two files with each other and who ever is the latest file, it gets compared with the third one and whichever file is latest gets compared with current date, and if its matches the current date, stop-process is called and if its lower a batch script is called, so far i have this from my previous script

```
$fileNameC = "D:\ForbesIT_Dental_Software_Backup\ClearBackUp.dat-bak"
$fileNameB = 
$filenameC = 

if ( test-path $fileNameA ) ( test-path $filenameB {
  if ( (get-item $fileName).LastWriteTime -ge (get-date).Date ) {
    stop-process -Id $PID
  }
else {
    start-process C:\ForbesIT\BackupCheck\backup_is_old.bat
     }  
  }
else {
    start-process C:\ForbesIT\BackupCheck\missing_folder.bat
  }
```

Comment: So you just want to compare the most recent of the 3 files then? Then, that file is compared today? We can do this. Would be nice if you included complete code next time as you don't have a `filea` and not all `file`s are populated. Also you dont really have a question here.

Comment: Sorry man new to this site, but i got confused on what variable to use.

Comment: No Problem. Welcome to So.

Comment: Sorry man new to this site, but i got confused on what variable to use. basically i want to compare three files to the current date and if one of them matches todays date then call a.bat and if it doesnt called old.bat and if the three mentioned files are not there then call missing.bat. I am getting confused on how to approach this. i created a basic script first which compares one file with current date and calls appropriate bat files there after but i an not sure how to modify the script to do what i want to do now.

Comment: if ( (get-item $fileName).LastWriteTime -ge (get-date).Date ) {
           stop-process -Id $PID
        }
           else {
                  start-process C:\ForbesIT\BackupCheck\backup_is_old.bat
                   }  
              }
else {
    start-process C:\ForbesIT\BackupCheck\missing_folder.bat
  }

Comment: the previous comment is my basic script i made before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built this based on what you said in the question.

```powershell
$file1 = "C:\temp\1.txt"
$file2 = "C:\temp\accounts.txt"
$file3 = "C:\temp\data.log2"

$files = $file1,$file2,$file3

If(!((test-path $files) -eq $false).Count){
    $newestFile = Get-Item $files | Sort-object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select -First 1
    If($newestFile.LastWriteTime -ge (get-date).Date){
        Stop-Process -Id $PID
    } Else {
        start-process C:\ForbesIT\BackupCheck\backup_is_old.bat
    }
} Else {
    start-process C:\ForbesIT\BackupCheck\missing_folder.bat
}
```

This will check all three of the `$file`s and find the newest one, based on `LastWriteTime`. Then compare that date and see if its from today. If it is then PowerShell quits. If the date is older then your batch is called.

I don't see how to fit in `start-process C:\ForbesIT\BackupCheck\missing_folder.bat` since you didn't bring it up in the question.

**Update From Comments**

I added another If `!((test-path $files) -eq $false).Count`. `test-path` will return an array of booleans. If any are false then the missing folder batch would be called. 0 when converted to boolean is false FYI.

Comment: wow thats amazing man, thank you soo much, let me test it with the files i have, thank you again. i appreciate it

Comment: basically that one is another else statement, if the filenames specified are missing for some reason call that missing_file.bat

Comment: I assumed as much. Is it if any or all are missing?

Comment: yes any or all, at any given time, those three files mentioned should be there but if any one of those or all of those are missing call missing_file.bat

Comment: @user2805361 Updated to account for missing files.